# R: how to use apply in dataset

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a dataset with susceptibilities of various drugs to different bacteria.
I would like to get the susceptibility frequencies by organism. Is there a way to streamline this, instead of copy/pasting for each drug?
I'm thinking using `apply` or maybe writing a function, but not sure where to start.

```r
pacman::p_load(tidyverse,
               janitor)

demo_dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 organism_name = c("Klebsiella pneumonia","Klebsiella pneumonia",
                                   "Escherichia coli","Klebsiella pneumonia",
                                   "Enterobacter cloacae","Escherichia coli",
                                   "Klebsiella pneumonia","Escherichia coli",
                                   "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                                   "Klebsiella pneumonia","Klebsiella pneumonia",
                                   "Escherichia coli","Klebsiella pneumonia",
                                   "Escherichia coli","Serratia marcenscens",
                                   "Klebsiella oxytoca","Escherichia coli",
                                   "Proteus mirabilis","Escherichia coli"),
                  amox_clav_po = c("S",
                                   "S","S","I","R","I","S","I","R","I",
                                   "S","S","S","S","I","R","S","S","S",
                                   "R"),
                    amp_sul_iv = c("S",
                                   "I","S","S","R","R","S","S","R","I",
                                   "S","I","S","I","R","R","S","S","S",
                                   "R"),
                   cefaclor_po = c("S",
                                   "S","S","S","R","S","S","S","S","S",
                                   "S","S","S","S","R","R","S","S","S",
                                   "S"),
                ceftriaxone_iv = c("S",
                                   "S","S","S","S","S","S","S","S","S",
                                   "S","S","S","S","R","S","S","S","S",
                                   "S")
            )

demo_dat |> 
  group_by(organism_name) |> 
  summarise(susceptibility = sum((amox_clav_po == "S")/n()))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   organism_name        susceptibility
#>   <chr>                         <dbl>
#> 1 Enterobacter cloacae          0    
#> 2 Escherichia coli              0.333
#> 3 Klebsiella oxytoca            1    
#> 4 Klebsiella pneumonia          0.857
#> 5 Proteus mirabilis             1    
#> 6 Serratia marcenscens          0

demo_dat |> 
  group_by(organism_name) |> 
  summarise(susceptibility = sum((amp_sul_iv == "S")/n()))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   organism_name        susceptibility
#>   <chr>                         <dbl>
#> 1 Enterobacter cloacae          0    
#> 2 Escherichia coli              0.444
#> 3 Klebsiella oxytoca            1    
#> 4 Klebsiella pneumonia          0.571
#> 5 Proteus mirabilis             1    
#> 6 Serratia marcenscens          0
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur ... 10.16
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       America/Phoenix
#>  date     2024-01-29
#>  pandoc   3.1.1 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package       * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat      0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  backports       1.4.1   2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  broom           1.0.1   2022-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  cellranger      1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  cli             3.6.1   2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  colorspace      2.0-3   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  crayon          1.5.2   2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  DBI             1.1.3   2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  dbplyr          2.2.1   2022-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  digest          0.6.30  2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  dplyr         * 1.1.2   2023-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  ellipsis        0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  evaluate        0.17    2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fansi           1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fastmap         1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  forcats       * 0.5.2   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fs              1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  gargle          1.2.1   2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  generics        0.1.3   2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  ggplot2       * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  glue            1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  googledrive     2.0.0   2021-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  googlesheets4   1.0.1   2022-08-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  gtable          0.3.1   2022-09-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  haven           2.5.1   2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  highr           0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  hms             1.1.2   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  htmltools       0.5.3   2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  httr            1.4.4   2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  janitor       * 2.1.0   2021-01-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  jsonlite        1.8.3   2022-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  knitr           1.40    2022-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  lifecycle       1.0.3   2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  lubridate       1.9.0   2022-11-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  magrittr        2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  modelr          0.1.9   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  munsell         0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pacman          0.5.1   2019-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pillar          1.9.0   2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pkgconfig       2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  purrr         * 1.0.1   2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  R6              2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  readr         * 2.1.3   2022-10-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  readxl          1.4.1   2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  reprex          2.0.2   2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rlang           1.1.1   2023-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rmarkdown       2.17    2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rstudioapi      0.14    2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rvest           1.0.3   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  scales          1.2.1   2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  sessioninfo     1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  snakecase       0.11.0  2019-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringi         1.7.8   2022-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringr       * 1.4.1   2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tibble        * 3.2.1   2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyr         * 1.2.1   2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyselect      1.2.0   2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyverse     * 1.3.2   2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  timechange      0.1.1   2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tzdb            0.4.0   2023-05-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  utf8            1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  vctrs           0.6.2   2023-04-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  withr           2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xfun            0.34    2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xml2            1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  yaml            2.3.6   2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Make your data tidy by creating columns that contain the drug name and route of administration rather than relying on column name to do this. Then group by both drug and route of administration. Then the solution you have taken from your now deleted previous question (bad form that, IMHO), will give you your answer.

Comment: @Limey Sorry, didn't realize that deleting a post was poor etiquette - I just figured it was redundant. Thanks for letting me know, I just undeleted the post.

Comment: Tim Thank you.  The reasons I believe deleting your question once it's answered is poor form are (1) it's discourteous to those who have taken time and effort to answer it and (2) it prevents anyone who, in the future, might have a similar problem from finding a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot and summarize:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- demo_dat |>
  pivot_longer(-organism_name) |>
  summarize(
    susceptibility = sum(value == "S")/n(),
    .by = c(organism_name, name)
  )

out
# # A tibble: 24 × 3
#    organism_name        name           susceptibility
#    <chr>                <chr>                   <dbl>
#  1 Klebsiella pneumonia amox_clav_po            0.857
#  2 Klebsiella pneumonia amp_sul_iv              0.571
#  3 Klebsiella pneumonia cefaclor_po             1    
#  4 Klebsiella pneumonia ceftriaxone_iv          1    
#  5 Escherichia coli     amox_clav_po            0.333
#  6 Escherichia coli     amp_sul_iv              0.444
#  7 Escherichia coli     cefaclor_po             0.889
#  8 Escherichia coli     ceftriaxone_iv          0.889
#  9 Enterobacter cloacae amox_clav_po            0    
# 10 Enterobacter cloacae amp_sul_iv              0    
# # ℹ 14 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Just to make sure we're seeing the same thing as your output,

```r
filter(out, name == "amox_clav_po")
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
#   organism_name        name         susceptibility
#   <chr>                <chr>                 <dbl>
# 1 Klebsiella pneumonia amox_clav_po          0.857
# 2 Escherichia coli     amox_clav_po          0.333
# 3 Enterobacter cloacae amox_clav_po          0    
# 4 Serratia marcenscens amox_clav_po          0    
# 5 Klebsiella oxytoca   amox_clav_po          1    
# 6 Proteus mirabilis    amox_clav_po          1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for all values and columns in your data. Then you could select those that has `S` if you want:

Using base R:

```
model.matrix(organism_name~0+., demo_dat)|>
    cbind(demo_dat['organism_name']) |>
    aggregate(.~organism_name, mean)

         organism_name amox_clav_poI amox_clav_poR amox_clav_poS amp_sul_ivR amp_sul_ivS cefaclor_poS ceftriaxone_ivS
1 Enterobacter cloacae     0.0000000     1.0000000     0.0000000   1.0000000   0.0000000    0.0000000       1.0000000
2     Escherichia coli     0.4444444     0.2222222     0.3333333   0.4444444   0.4444444    0.8888889       0.8888889
3   Klebsiella oxytoca     0.0000000     0.0000000     1.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000    1.0000000       1.0000000
4 Klebsiella pneumonia     0.1428571     0.0000000     0.8571429   0.0000000   0.5714286    1.0000000       1.0000000
5    Proteus mirabilis     0.0000000     0.0000000     1.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000    1.0000000       1.0000000
6 Serratia marcenscens     0.0000000     1.0000000     0.0000000   1.0000000   0.0000000    0.0000000       1.0000000
```

---

if you store the results above into a variable `results` you can get the `S` that you want as:

```
cbind(results['organism_name'],results[endsWith(names(results), 'S')])

         organism_name amox_clav_poS amp_sul_ivS cefaclor_poS ceftriaxone_ivS
1 Enterobacter cloacae     0.0000000   0.0000000    0.0000000       1.0000000
2     Escherichia coli     0.3333333   0.4444444    0.8888889       0.8888889
3   Klebsiella oxytoca     1.0000000   1.0000000    1.0000000       1.0000000
4 Klebsiella pneumonia     0.8571429   0.5714286    1.0000000       1.0000000
5    Proteus mirabilis     1.0000000   1.0000000    1.0000000       1.0000000
6 Serratia marcenscens     0.0000000   0.0000000    0.0000000       1.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

r2evans and Onyambu have given you two perfectly reasonable answers to your problem, but here's another variation that I think is worth mentioning.  I think it's worthwhile becauase (1) it demonstrates the principles of [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)ness; (2) it's a generic solution; (3) it's potentially more robust and (4) to my eyes at least, it is both more compact and easier to understand - and hence to maintain.

Your data set is not tidy because information you need to perform your analysis (the drug name and route of andministration) is contained in the column names rather than in the values in the dara frame.

So, the first thing to do is to make the data frame tidy:

```
longData <- demo_dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -organism_name,
    names_to = c("Drug", "Route"),
    values_to = "Susceptibility",
    names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)$"
  )

longData 
# A tibble: 80 × 4
   organism_name        Drug        Route Susceptibility
   <chr>                <chr>       <chr> <chr>         
 1 Klebsiella pneumonia amox_clav   po    S             
 2 Klebsiella pneumonia amp_sul     iv    S             
 3 Klebsiella pneumonia cefaclor    po    S             
 4 Klebsiella pneumonia ceftriaxone iv    S             
 5 Klebsiella pneumonia amox_clav   po    S             
 6 Klebsiella pneumonia amp_sul     iv    I             
 7 Klebsiella pneumonia cefaclor    po    S             
 8 Klebsiella pneumonia ceftriaxone iv    S             
 9 Escherichia coli     amox_clav   po    S             
10 Escherichia coli     amp_sul     iv    S             
# ℹ 70 more rows
```

The only slightly tricky thing here is the extraction of the drug name and route of administration from the column names. `names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)$"` indicates that I want to extract two pieces of information (indicated by the bracketed groups).  The second ends at the end of the string (`$`) and consists of everything between the last underscore and end of the string.  The first consists of everything between the start of the string and the last underscore. [The underscore in `"amox_clav"` means we need to take this slightly awkward approach.]

Now it's easy to get the information you want:

```
longData %>% 
  group_by(organism_name, Drug, Route) %>% 
  summarise(Percentage = (sum(Susceptibility == "S") / n()), .groups = "drop")
# A tibble: 24 × 4
   organism_name        Drug        Route Percentage
   <chr>                <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>
 1 Enterobacter cloacae amox_clav   po         0    
 2 Enterobacter cloacae amp_sul     iv         0    
 3 Enterobacter cloacae cefaclor    po         0    
 4 Enterobacter cloacae ceftriaxone iv         1    
 5 Escherichia coli     amox_clav   po         0.333
 6 Escherichia coli     amp_sul     iv         0.444
 7 Escherichia coli     cefaclor    po         0.889
 8 Escherichia coli     ceftriaxone iv         0.889
 9 Klebsiella oxytoca   amox_clav   po         1    
10 Klebsiella oxytoca   amp_sul     iv         1    
# ℹ 14 more rows
```

The reason I claim this solution is more robust is that it will work for any combination of drug name and route, regardless of format and regardless of the values of drug name and route.  It's also easily generalisable to other classifications: for example using dose or formulation.

Comment: Other than splitting a variable into two columns (never suggested as an issue by the OP), how is this different from my answer? You split it, but that can just as easily be done _after_ the summarization with no change in results (add `tidyr::separate_wider_regex(name, patterns=c(Drug=".*", "_", Route="[^_]+"))` to my answer). I don't care about the reps, really, but this answer adds nothing new to the requested issue.

Comment: @r2evans To a very large extent, I agree with you.  The only clearly additional infomation is with regard to the benefits of tidyness, which I believe is a reasonable comment.  I did not post in attempt to take your rep away and was surprised when OP changed thewir accepted answer.  By means of this comment, I request that OP reverts to their original acceptance of r2evan's answer, which has precedence over this one.

Comment: Again, not concerned with the rep, and I recognize you aren't trying to "steal" the accepted-answer or reps. My complaint is two-fold: (1) mostly same code, same results, though I now concede that your commentary adds value; (2) the assertion that my answer is not tidy, not generic, not robust, and not compact/easy-to-read, since the only differences between our code is that yours does two blocks, and yours splits into `Drug`/`Route` before the summarizing (which does not change the resulting percentages).